# Celery configuration in Django, connecting tasks to the view

Tags: python-3.x, celery, django-celery, celery-task, django-1.11

I've recently configured celery to run some dummy tasks, and ran the workers through Terminal on my Mac. It all seems to run accordingly, took a while, since some of the literature out there seems to advise different configuration scenarios, but I got there anyway. Now the next step is to trigger the tasks via my view in Django. I'm using **celery 1.2.26.post2**

My project structure:

```
/MyApp
   celery_tasks.py
   celeryconfig.py
   __init__.py
```

I've been following several tutorials and found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDoHrFLkahA) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waD4MEj8WGw) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZkZr7apcJs) very helpful to obtain an overall view of celery.

My scripts are:

**celery_tasks.py**

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.task import task

app = Celery()                          # Initialise the app
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')  # Tell Celery instance to use celeryconfig module


suf = lambda n: "%d%s" % (n, {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}.get(n if n < 20 else n % 10, "th"))
@task
def fav_doctor():
    """Reads doctor.txt file and prints out fav doctor, then adds a new
    number to the file"""

    with open('doctor.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            nums = line.rstrip().split()

            print ('The {} doctor is my favorite'.format(suf(int(nums[0]))))

            for num in nums[1:]:
                print ('Wait! The {} doctor is my favorite'.format(suf(int(num))))

            last_num = int(nums[-1])
            new_last_num = last_num + 1

            f.write(str(new_last_num) + ' ')


@task
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]

@task
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
from datetime import timedelta

## List of modules to import when celery starts.
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('celery_tasks',)

## Message Broker (RabbitMQ) settings.
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://'
BROKER_PORT = 5672
#BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'sqlalchemy'
#BROKER_HOST = 'sqlite:///tasks.db'
#BROKER_VHOST = '/'
#BROKER_USER = 'guest'
#BROKER_PASSWORD = 'guest'

## Result store settings.
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
#CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = 'sqlite:///mydatabase.db'

## Worker settings
#CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1
#CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 20
#CELERYD_LOG_FILE = 'celeryd.log'
#CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'

## Misc
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'doctor-every-10-seconds': {
        'task': 'celery_tasks.fav_doctor',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3),
    },
}
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .celery_tasks import app as celery_app # Ensures app is always imported when Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

In **settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
     'djcelery',
]
```

In my views folder, I have a specific view module, **admin_scripts.py**

```
from MyApp.celery_tasks import fav_doctor, reverse, send_email, add

@login_required
def admin_script_dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Admin_Script(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            backup_script_select = form.cleaned_data['backup_script_select']
            dummy_script_select = form.cleaned_data['dummy_script_select']
            print ("backup_script_select: {0}".format(backup_script_select))
            print ("dummy_script_select: {0}".format(dummy_script_select))
            if backup_script_select:
                print ("Backup script exectuting. Please wait...")
                dbackup_script_dir =  str(Path.home()) + '/Software/MyOtherApp/cli-tools/dbbackup_DRAFT.py'
                subprocess.call(" python {} ".format(dbackup_script_dir), shell=True)
                async_result = reverse.delay('Using Celery')
                print ("async_result: {0}".format(async_result))
                result = reverse.AsyncResult(async_result.id)
                print ("result: {0}".format(result))
                print ("Something occured...")
            if dummy_script_select:
                print ("Dummy script exectuting. Please wait...")
                dummy_script_dir =  str(Path.home()) + '/Software/MyOtherApp/cli-tools/dummy.py'
                subprocess.call(" python {} ".format(dummy_script_dir), shell=True)
                async_result = add.delay(2, 5)
                print ("async_result: {0}".format(async_result))
                result = add.AsyncResult(async_result.id)
                print ("result: {0}".format(result))
                print ("Something occured...")
            return render(request, 'MyApp/admin_scripts_db.html')
```

The problem occurs at the line in my **admin_scripts.py** file, where `async_result = add.delay(2, 5)` is called. Below the traceback:

```
[12/Jul/2018 09:23:19] ERROR [django.request:135] Internal Server Error: /MyProject/adminscripts/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 309, in _get_current_object
    return object.__getattribute__(self, '__thing')
AttributeError: 'PromiseProxy' object has no attribute '__thing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 323, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'conf'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 158, in _smart_import
    return imp(path)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 112, in import_from_cwd
    package=package,
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 106, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celeryconfig'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/Software/MyProject/MyProjectsite/MyProject/views/admin_scripts.py", line 44, in admin_script_dashboard
    async_result = add.delay(2, 5)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 143, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 311, in _get_current_object
    return self.__evaluate__()
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 341, in __evaluate__
    thing = Proxy._get_current_object(self)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 101, in _get_current_object
    return loc(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 270, in _task_from_fun
    '__wrapped__': fun}, **options))()
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 201, in __new__
    instance.bind(app)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 365, in bind
    conf = app.conf
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 325, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 638, in conf
    return self._get_config()
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 454, in _get_config
    self.loader.config_from_object(self._config_source)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 140, in config_from_object
    obj = self._smart_import(obj, imp=self.import_from_cwd)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 161, in _smart_import
    return symbol_by_name(path, imp=imp)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 112, in import_from_cwd
    package=package,
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
    return imp(module, package=package)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 106, in import_module
    return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
  File "/Users/MyMBP/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celeryconfig'
```

Numerous errors get thrown, and the traceback is very large, about 9000 lines long in total. This is just a snippet. I'm new to celery and task queueing in general, so perhaps for some of the experts out there you can pick out some very obvious mistakes from my code.

As I said, the configuration of celery is successful, and when triggering the tasks in Terminal, the tasks do what they are supposed to do. I'm building this up piece by piece, so this next step is to trigger the tasks using my view in Django (instead of being called using Terminal). Once I have figured that out, then the ultimate aim is to track the progress of a task, and report the output to the user in a separate window (.js, AJAX etc.) that shows for example the line output that you see in Console.

I read that the tasks.py (in my case celery_tasks.py) file needs to be in a django app that's registered in settings.py. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but may help partly others who encounter a similar issue:

Basically in the `celery_tasks.py` there is the following:

```
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
```

When I trigger the workers through Terminal, this works. When I do it via my view, then the error message above can be seen. Changing this line works via the view:

```
app.config_from_object('MyApp.celeryconfig')
```

I still need to figure out why there is this discrepancy and how to resolve this so that it is indifferent whether the Tasks are called via my view or Terminal.